# After writing to NTFS partition from Ubuntu, Windows sees it as RAW

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ntfs, data-corruption

I have a dual boot on 2 SSDs: 1)Windows7 (main) 2)Ubuntu 17.10.

After copying a folder from Ubuntu to Windows NTFS partition and rebooting Windows stopped  recognizing this partition as NTFS (DISKPART shows RAW) and can't boot from it at all partition.

Chkdsk shows something like `Corrupt master file table... cannot recover`.

When I try to mount this partition under Ubuntu - it shows error message:
[image]

I tried to use ntfsfix, shows the same input:

`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb2`

```
Mounting volume... ntfs_mapping_pairs_decompress() failed: Input/output error
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... ntfs_mapping_pairs_decompress() failed: Input/output error
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Input/output error
Checking for self-located MFT segment... OK
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

I tried TestDisk, didn't help

I created windows VM on my ubuntu and installed Acronis Revive on it, Acronis Revive allows to do scan and even quick scanning SHOWS ALL FILES AND FOLDERS and allow to restore it (saving to another drive), but how to restore the partition's MFT instead of cherry picking?

Please help!!!

Comment: I've had good luck with the program `testdisk` in the past: https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: You need to repair the NTFS partition boot sector. Usually you can restore from backup. You want to get to this screen:
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#NTFS_Boot_sector_recovery
[HowTo] Repair the bootsector of a Windows partition  - YannBuntu
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix
 RAW  means the boot sector was erased. Do you have Windows fast start up on, which is hibernation. And then forcing write would corrupt it.

Comment: TestDisk didn't help, more over it actually corrupted it more when I  copied MFT Mirror to MTF. I researched with low level disk editor, that Bootsector is fine, the problem is corrupted (and absent) file system metadata records including $MFT (Master File Table), $root (#5), $BitMap, $Secure etc. Surprisingly I didn't find any tools that automatically recreate it by scanning the ntfs's FILE-records, the best thing I found is just cherry picking of files/folders to recover using Acronis or similar tools

Comment: @oldfred a damaged MFT has nothing to do with the boot sector.